# DRY way to change working directory for npm scripts

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

I'm just trying out NPM as my build system for a small project and I'd like to ask if there is a clean and easy to maintain way to change the working directory for the build scripts. My first thought was something like

```
"scripts": {
    "cd:workdir": "cd src/path/to/my/work/dir/",
    "task:1": "npm run cd:workdir && command1",
    "task:2": "npm run cd:workdir && command2",
    [...]
  }
```

But it seams `command*` is executed in a different process then `npm run cd:workdir`, so this doesn't work.

The only working way I found so far is:

```
"scripts": {
    "task:1": "cd src/path/to/my/work/dir/ && command1",
    "task:2": "cd src/path/to/my/work/dir/ && command2",
    [...]
  }
```

But there must be a better way to do this to keep it DRY and better maintainable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `child_process.exec` to execute some commands from a javascript file:

```js
// task.js
const { exec } = require('child_process');

exec('command', {
  cwd: 'src/path/to/my/work/dir/'
}, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  // handle error, stderr...

  console.log(stdout)
});
```

and execute that javascript file using node in npm script: `"task:1": "node task.js"`

Comment: Yes that works, but this is not exactly what I was hoping for. I'd need a javascript file for each command or I could write the complete build script in javascript which would make npm scripts obsolete. I guess the huge drawback of using npm scripts is the limitation caused by the json config file.